# How to easily synchronise two folders (1 on PC, 1 on external HDD)

Tags: windows-7, sync

I like to synchronise a specific folder on my PC with another folder on my external hard drive. Both folders' contents change frequently and changes are independent from each other. The process will occur daily, so I want a fast, secure, user-friendly and free tool for that. I'm running Windows 7 Home Professional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52&displaylang=en)**  is a free application that synchronizes files and folders between locations.

[image]

If you're using **[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)**, it can easily synchronize/compare folders:

[image]

Comment: SyncToy is what I need. Thanks & Keep up the good work, dude! ;)

Comment: you're more than welcome.